# Two Visualforce Page Same Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, global-variables, modal

I have an issue that I am using two VF page with common controller. One VF Page is normal and other is opened as a modal on the 1st Visualforce page.
I am adding some elements on 1st VF page in a list and when i open the other VF page that list comes empty.

```
 public class commonController {
     public List<CategoryWrapper> lstSelectedWrapper {get; set;}
     public SearchProductsController(){
         //objId is being passed from 1st page. objId != NULL when 2nd page is opened.
         if(Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('objId') == NULL) {
             lstSelectedWrapper = new List<CategoryWrapper>();
         }
     }
     public void methodFrom1stpage() {
         //Add elements to list lstSelectedWrapper 
     }
     public void methodFrom2ndPage() {
         System.debug(lstSelectedWrapper ); //This coming empty/null
     }
}
```

Please help me out of this.

Comment: How you are showing modal window? Can you post some code snippet?

Comment: Using the iframe:- <apex:iframe src="/apex/2ndPage?objId={!obj.Id} width="100%" height="758px" scrolling="false" rendered="{!if(obj.Id != null, true, false)}"  />

Answer (score 3):

Both of the pages will have a separate instance of the controller. The pages will not share a view state and their controllers can not communicate with each other. If you want to do something like this you will have to pass GET or POST variables or use an object to store the data that you want to transport between the two pages.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to pass the GET or POST variables?

Comment: @AKSHAYDhiman This is a good answer. Although I'd ask as to whether anything is wrong with using [bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) style modals?

Comment: The page was not written by me and i have just implement this part in it.  And client does not want does nit want me to change the ui at all.

Comment: @AKSHAYDhiman this is one of those times where it benefits to have a discussion with the client and offer a better solution. Not just blindly take a bad requirement and implement it.